# Puzzle: using only 2 variables find which element is most frequent in an array

Tags: arrays, puzzle

You have a stream that can contain n integers. However it can only contain two diverse values but you do not know upfront which ones they are. Ex: (7,7,4,4,7,7,4), (-1, 6, -1, -1, -1), (0,1,0,0,1,0,1).

Using **only two named variables** (the problem is limited in memory space), can you find which of the two numbers is repeated the most (that means is n = m, n > m or viceversa)?
Suppose you have this API hasNext() that return true if there are more elements in the array , next() move on the next element, and inspect() that returns the current element in the array. There is no way to go back or rewind the stream.

Comment: that's not what SO is intended for

Comment: `can you find which of the two numbers` - yes, we can.

Comment: BTW.: `two integer variables`: I assumed you mean `two named variables`, not including temporaries or automatic stack variables. Also, there is no mention of the target platform nor language nor Array's purpose. So, given the text, there is no assumption that the Array is readonly, hence, just for fun, I'd use it as intermediate store for n<=1000 extra variables (after reading the head of course). Ah, sorry, this Array has an "API". Ok, no writing, pity.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but dear, make your puzzles at least well-written. Regarding API: What your API describes is not array but rather a stream or sequence. Arrays should be random-access, indexed. The API you described forms a non-random-access, forward-only reading. Even more: that stream is one-time-readable, is it?! Your API does not have "rewind" or "reset" method, so we probably should assume that after hasNext/next'ing once through all the elements we have no way to go back.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. One variable records the number currently in the lead, and the other records the size of the lead:

```
leading = stream.inspect()
lead = 0
while stream.hasNext():
    stream.next()
    if leading == stream.inspect():
        lead += 1
    elif lead > 0:
        lead -= 1
    else:
        leading = stream.inspect()
        lead = 1
```